# FabricJS - How to get Delta on transformation?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there is a way to get a delta/distance from the last move in FabricJS by using a native function or attribute?
Assume, current coordinates are 100x100. 
Now I moving an element and it's new coordinates are 90x120.
So, the delta is -10x20 and this is what I need to get using FabricJS functions or native js code.

Any ideas?
Tnx

Comment: seems like difference between left(x) and top(y) coordinates

Comment: Delta = difference... but to get it?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 60,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
});
canvas.add(rect);
rect.on('mousedown', rectMouseDown);
rect.on('mouseup', rectMouseUp);

function rectMouseDown(){
 this.origPos = this.getCenterPoint();
}

function rectMouseUp(){
 delta = this.getCenterPoint().subtract(this.origPos);
 console.log(delta.x,delta.y)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

on mouse down and mouse up on object, take center point coordinate using `getCenterPoint()` and to get delta use [subtract](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Point.html#subtract).

Comment: @EugeneVilder you just need to get the difference of left and top. Thats what subtract function returns.

Comment: Since top and left could be configurable from attributes panel, not by moving object, I can't use Mouse events.